# Why does string support `operator=(char)`?

Tags: c++, c++11

A colleague of mine today uncovered a very subtle bug in our code, which basically went like this:

```
double d = 65;
std::string s = "Hello world";

// .. somewhere later, accidentally assigning to s instead of a similarly
// named numerical variable.
s = d;

// s is now 'A'
```

The reason that this bug can occur, I found, is that `std::basic_string<_Elem>` has an assignment operator

```
_Myt& operator=(_Elem _Ch)
{ // assign 1 * _Ch
  return (assign(1, _Ch));
}
```

Now the compiler doesn't really complain (a lot, it emits a warning about the narrowing conversion if the level is sufficiently high). It seems we caught this bug early enough that it did not do a lot of damage, but I was wondering why this is allowed. After all, I cannot write

```
std::string s = 65;
```

because `std::string` does not have a(n implicit) constructor which takes a `char`. Wouldn't it be safer to make it an explicit conversion which forces you to write

```
std::string s = string('A');
```

and that would prohibit assignment to a single `_Elem` (`char`).

Is there any reason this assignment operator was provided? As the same colleague correctly noticed,

```
double d;
char c = d;
```

is allowed whereas

```
int* p = d;
```

is not (for any pointer size) - presumably because the implicit conversion from number to pointer is deemed dangerous.
In fact, it even seems to have made it into C++11 which, as far as I have seen, tries to be quite strict and helpful in data type management.

Comment: This is why you always set the warnings high! "both a double and a char fit in four bytes" not sure what this means. They are different sizes.

Comment: @NeilKirk Why isn't the default, as-installed warning level high?  Nobody wants their compiler to be the first to bury their customers' code in a sea of warnings about all their bad practices?

Comment: "it even seems to have made it into C++11" - because removing it would break 30ish years of legacy code, so is not something to do lightly.

Comment: @Poldie If you have to use unchangeable third-party code which has warnings, that is a bit of a different situation. I guess my "always" was exaggerated.

Comment: That's it. I remember a compiler giving a warning when a function overload with different types hid functions in the base class (a very hard to find bug), and so many idiots not understanding the warning complained, so it got removed. And then everyone else complained, and they put the warning back in :-)

Comment: @NeilKirk Fair enough. Although you could always have high warnings but not warning = error, or you could pragma away warnings you're happy with.

Comment: I suggest you to use the highest available warning level, and selectively disable the warnings you get, after you understood them and decided you want to live with them.

Comment: @GiulioFranco that is exactly how we caught this bug and disarmed it. The observation was more generally that some dangerous conversions seem to be disallowed while others only emit a high warning level warning.

Comment: @CompuChip Welcome to C++

Comment: There should be a book. "C++: the nasty dirty bits" or something like that.

Comment: @n.m. there are numerous books, I read "(More) Effective C++" a while back.

Comment: Thanks @remyabel, I hadn't found that (searching for things like `double` and `int` combined with `string` and `assignment` or `conversion` mostly gives questions about convering an integer like 123 to a string `"123"`). Still, I managed to find the _explanation_ by looking at the documentation, I guess my question was more _why_ this strange assignment operator (still) exists - which, apparently, seems to be "for legacy reasons".

Comment: @CompuChip the C++ standard is mainly run by big companies, with lots of legacy code they don't want to touch anymore. Only recently there's been some opening about non-backwards-compatible changes.

Comment: This is pretty much [LWG issue 2372](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2372), though it covers other integers and not floating point types.

Answer (score 15):

Somebody 30 years ago who wrote the library from which `std::string` was imported thought it was a good idea.

Before standardization it was not removed.

Since then, removing it would risk breaking legacy code, which is a cost.

The `deprecated` attribute was only added recently to C++, which allows a standard way to tell the user of a function that it will go away shortly.  Nobody has managed to make it deprecated, which is a sensible step required before it would be removed (just removing it would be rude).  I encourage you to make such a proposal.

Comment: I'd suggest adding the [[deprecated]] attribute to that member function and remove it by C++17. After all, it can easily be replaced by assignment to a braced-init-list, e.g. `s = {'5'};`

Comment: @Columbo Removing it by C++17 seems overly aggressive: it should be deprecated for at least one standard-revision before it is removed.  I would argue `[[deprecated]]` for C++17, then propose removing it in C++2x or C++2y.

Comment: Whoops! My mistake. I meant to say "by the standard after C++17". Clearly we can only introduce the attribute in C++17. :)

Comment: @Columbo agile standard writing

Comment: Two things. First, `std::string` was not imported from an existing library. It was designed specifically for the C++ standard library. Second, deprecated does not mean that something will go away (shortly or otherwise). It means only that it **might** go away. For example, the C standard headers are part of C++, but deprecated. They're never going to go away. (And, of course, they shouldn't be deprecated, but that's another matter)